# 2d arrays issue connected with passing a filled array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, multidimensional-array

I'm working with c++ arrays and I found a problem. I can easily do the exercise using cin and filling array with for loop. But when I try to do it as filled array I got the error with too many initializer values. How to solve it?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func(int **arr, int row, int col)
{
   for (int i=0; i<row; i++)
   {
      for(int j=0 ; j<col; j++)
      {
        cout<<arr[i][j]<<" ";
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
}

int main()
{
    int row = 2;
    int colum = 2;

    int** arr = new int*[row];
    for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new int[colum];
    }
    arr = {
        {1,2},
        {3,4}};
    func(arr, row, colum);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us this error?  I suspect it has to do with whether or not `arr` is a pointer to an array of pointers.

Comment: `arr = {{1,2},{3,4}};` is an initialization trick and cannot be used with assignment.

Comment: Note: You don't really have a 2D array. You have an array of pointers to arrays. This is often much harder to work with. C++ doesn't have dynamically sized 2D arrays, but it is fairly easy to perform the indexing math yourself and use a 1D array as though it was 2D.

Comment: So how can I change this to use it with ceratin array like 1,2 3,4?

Comment: *I'm working with c++ arrays and I found a problem* -- That's why `std::array` was created.

Comment: @Michau123 -- If the array is only 2x2, why even dynamically allocate anything?  Just use a 2x2 "regular" array.

Comment: `arr` is an `int**`, not an array. (Despite persistent rumours to the contrary, arrays are not pointers.) And even if it were an array, you can't assign to arrays.

Answer (score 1):

arr is a pointer

```
int** arr = new int*[row];
```

So it may be initialized with a braced list containing only one (assignment) expression.

For the allocated array of two elements you could write for example

```
int** arr = new int*[row];
for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
{
    if ( i == 0 ) arr[i] = new int[colum] { 1, 2 };
    else arr[i] = new int[colum] { 3, 4 };
}
```

or

```
int** arr = new int*[row];
for(int i=0, value = 1; i<row; i++)
{
    arr[i] = new int[colum] { value++, value++ };
}
```

Pay attention to that you will need to free the dynamically allocated memory for the arrays.

Otherwise use the standard container `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` instead of the allocated dynamically arrays.